# AC voltage rating of the capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ac, ratings

I am using a capacitor which is rated for 630V DC. I want to know the AC voltage rating for this capacitor.

[This is the capacitor.](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TDK/CGA6N4NP02J223J230AA/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsh%252B1woXyUXj5T3QdfXN%252BsfUc2H8WHRHg8%3D)

[This is its datasheet.](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/mlcc_automotive_hightemp_en.pdf?ref_disty=mouser)

Comment: What does the datasheet say? If there is no AC rating then there is no rating, meaning that you're on your own if you use this capacitor with AC. From the AC voltage (peak, RMS etc.) it can be calculated what the maximum voltage is and that should be lower than the DC rating. However, a capacitor without an AC rating isn't **guaranteed** to work safely with AC. So a smart engineer would simply select a different capacitor (with an AC rating).

Comment: <after looking at datasheet> Indeed these capacitors have no AC rating. They appear to be designed for electric cars with high DC voltages. I would **NOT** use this type of capacitor with (mains) AC, they're not designed for that. If you ignore this advice and the capacitors blow up and/or start smoking and/or catch fire then don't complain to me or to TDK. Choose a different model capacitor.

Comment: How are you going to use this capacitor? Do you intend to use this capacitor with AC mains voltage?

Comment: Yea cool, But I could not find any capacitor in this range with 5% tolerance or less. lets say if i need to operate at 600VAC then I can use the above capacitor 2 in series, which will be ok right?

Comment: I will be using this in the resonant converter which is secondary side

Comment: The word "current" or "amp" doesn't appear in that datasheet. Find capacitors that do mention the current rating across a range of frequencies. Then you can be assured.

Comment: At an absolute minimum the AC voltage across the cap should be less than its DC rating and ideally less or substantially less. As Vpeak AC is always greater than the DC equivalent value the chance of it being safe at 600 VAC is about zero. There are then other issues which others have noted.

Comment: Manjesh - Please put all available information in the question eg "I will be using this in the resonant converter which is secondary side " is vital information which would have been much better in the original question and should be added. Plus anything else known and even possibly relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AC voltage rating is the maximum Voltage the capacitor can handle divided by the square root of 2.

So this capacitor can handle 630V / 1,414 = **445,5V**

I wouldn't go higher than 400VAC though.

Comment: Nick - that's for a sine wave. He notes in a comment "I will be using this in the resonant converter which is secondary side ". That may well be sinusoidal, but needs confirmation.